# Dismiss keyboard from UISearchBar when adding as a subview

Tags: objective-c, search

I wanted to add a UISearchBar to my view controller without storyboard so I added it programmatically as a subview. I have set the delegate and yet I can't seem to dismiss the keyboard by clicking on the search button.

here's my code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UISearchBar* mySearchBar;
}
----
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [mySearchBar setDelegate: self];
    mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y, 320, 44)];
    [self.view addSubview:mySearchBar];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)mySearchBar
{
    [mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)mySearchBar
{
    [mySearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This is not related to Xcode by any means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the delegate before allocating the search bar. Try to set delegate afterwards.

```
mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y, 320, 44)];
[mySearchBar setDelegate: self];
```

It is always helpful to check whether the delegate methods are called in the first place. Set a break point and see :)